# Mechanics - Motion round a vertical circle

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A ball of mass 100 grams is hanging from a fixed point by a string 2.5 metres long. It is struck with a bat so that it starts to describe a circle in a vertical plane. When the ball reaches a height of 4 metres the string becomes slack. Find the speed of the ball immediately after it was struck and the tension in the string at that instant.

PS - I know how to find the tension at that instant, but finding the value for the speed is quite a challenge for me. I have used energy conservation principle to equate 0.5 mu^2 to (m x g x 4 + 0.5 x m x v^2) - but how do I find the speed of the ball at this height? If there's any other way anyone suggests I could do this question, please ...

Comment: How everyone in this thread missed the big, bold "**MATHEMATICS**" logo at the top of the page is beyond me.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It seems to be well toward the "physics" end of the "mathematical-physics" tag, but if you think this is posted to the wrong board, flag it for migration to physics.SE or wherever you think it belongs. Reflexively downvoting everything is not the most constructive action.

Comment: @DavidK [physics.se] forbids this type of homework questions, so the migration will be rejected. Off-topic question => downvote and vote to close. Answer to an off-topic question, encouraging others to post more off-topic questions => downvote. And the burden is not on me to find a website where this question could be posted; it's on OP. I can vote to close and downvote if the question isn't fit for math.SE without suggesting another website.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Good point about Physics.SE; they are more like MathOverflow in that regard. On the other hand, MSE is not MO. We do like OP to do most of the work and narrow down the problem to where a hint will suffice, which in this case is true. However, the hint involves using physical principles to set up an equation. So the question would appear to be homeless for that reason.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At any instant while the ball is in its circular "orbit" around
the fixed point, the force of gravity on the ball can be
broken down into two perpendicular components,
one component in the direction of travel (tangent to the circle)
and one perpendicular to the direction of travel
(along the radius of the circle).

When the ball is in the lower half of the circle, the radial
component of gravity pulls the ball away from the fixed point.
The tension in the string has to be enough so that *after* canceling
the radial component of gravity, there is just enough force to
keep the ball traveling along the circle.
But in the upper half of the circle, the radial
component of gravity pulls the ball toward the fixed point.
When the radial component of gravity alone is sufficient to
bend the path of the ball along the circular arc,
the tension in the string is zero and the string goes slack.

After that point the centripetal force is greater than required
and the ball will travel inside the circle, but we're not
asked to concern ourselves with that.

You can work out the radial direction at the height of $4$ meters,
from which you can determine the force of gravity in that direction.
You should then be able to work backward to get velocity at that instant.

Comment: One downvote for answering an off-topic question (which I'm starting to think this may be), one downvote apparently because someone doesn't know how to do force component analysis in any direction except up/down and horizontal.

Comment: [And here is why you don't answer off-topic questions.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1653014/10014) You're just encouraging them to do it again.

Answer (score -1):

The thread became slack $\implies$ $Tension = 0$  at that 4m height. When tension is 0, velocity of the ball is zero as well (consider $tension = $$mv^2\over r$ ( centrifugal force) )  So, speed at that height is 0. 
Well, this is maths exchange after all, you are not supposed to ask these questions.

Comment: And **you** are not supposed to answer off-topic questions (nor are you expected to give what looks like a nonsense answer). -1

Comment: OP did not explicitly write the equation of motion given the two forces on the ball (tension and gravity), but gravity nevertheless is part of that equation, even at the instant when the string goes slack. This answer ignores it.

Comment: @DavidK Please understand properly.. Gravity acts in the vertical direction only. Take the horizontal components of tension and centrifugal force. You get velocity is 0.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Though I did give the answer, It's only to help a person. Why did you even come to the question when it's not your topic? Just leave it alone if you dont want to be be soo pessimistic.

Comment: @WinVineeth Centripetal force is horizontal only when the ball is traveling straight up or down, at height 2.5. At height 4, centripetal force is at less than 90 degree angle to the gravitational force, therefore gravity has a non-zero component in that direction. If anything, this answer is starting to convince me that Najib is right, this question should never have been asked here.

Comment: @DavidK You are getting confused again. I am asking you to consider the horizontal components which should be equal. Please read properly. As far as the question, you are right. It should not be asked here.

Comment: @WinVineeth The relevant components are in the direction of travel (tangential) and perpendicular to direction of travel (radial). I'm sure you can do this with horizontal and vertical components, but it's more complicated: at the moment the string goes slack, you have to account for the force keeping the ball on the circle and the force slowing it down; those two forces are perpendicular to each other but not horizontal or vertical; if you work out their horizontal/vertical components, the horizontal cancels but the vertical adds up to the force of gravity.